# Apktool error Terminal inquiry

Tags: android, paths

when I run Apktool to build a package for android I get this output:

> :~$ apktool build '/home/...'    I: Checking whether sources has
>   changed...   I: Checking whether resources has changed...    I:
>   Building resources...   Exception in thread "main"
>   brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException:
>   could not exec command: aapt, p, -F,
>   /tmp/APKTOOL3418222472327622786.tmp, -I,
>   /home/apktool/framework/1.apk, -S, /home/.../
>   /home/.../AndroidManifest.xml]    at
>   brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.aaptPackage(AndrolibResources.java:255)
>     at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResourcesFull(Androlib.java:324)     at
>   brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResources(Androlib.java:269)  at
>   brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:192)   at
>   brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:174)   at
>   brut.apktool.Main.cmdBuild(Main.java:188)     at
>   brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:70) Caused by:
>   brut.common.BrutException: could not exec command: [aapt, p, -F,
>   /tmp/APKTOOL3418222472327622786.tmp, -I,
>   /home/.../.../framework/1.apk, -S, /home/.../.../res, -M,
>   /home/.../.../AndroidManifest.xml]    at brut.util.OS.exec(OS.java:87)
>     at
>   brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.aaptPackage(AndrolibResources.java:253)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "aapt":
>   java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory   at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:475)   at
>   java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:610)  at
>   java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:483)  at
>   brut.util.OS.exec(OS.java:78)     ... 7 more Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or
>   directory     at java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:164)   at
>   java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:81)  at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:468)   ... 10 more

It seems like a PATH problem because it can't access aapt however my PATH is located in ~/pam_enviorment 
and is the following:

```
PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:~/myTerminal                                        
PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:~/myTerminal/aapt
```

Any constructive feedback is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

As of apktool v1.5.1 I added support for passing the path to apktool via `--aapt`/`-a`, so on rebuild just use `apktool b --aapt /path/to/aapt nameofapkfolder`. So update your apktool and forget messing around with path variables.

As for the path problem. What happens on `echo $PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

It definitely seems like the aapt PATH problem I had a while back. I'm sure you have this all sorted out by now, but for other Linux users who may have the same problem, I have made a good apk kit in bash to avoid all these dependency problems called [apk munky-rench](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/development/toolkit-apk-munky-rench-t3026757/post58747626#post58747626). Check it out.

At initial release, apk munky-rench has the following features:

- Unzip Apk
- Zip APK
- Install Frameworks
- Decompile Apk
- Compile Apk
- Sign Apk
- Zipalign Apk
- Compile System Apk
- ADB Install
- ADB Push/Pull
- Fastboot Flash Recovery
- Heimdall Flash Recovery
- Supports Samsung devices through onboard Heimdall
- Flashable Zip Generator
- Lollipop Compatibility
- Brief Explanations of Features